# substring XSLT over multiple value lines for an atttribute

Tags: xslt, substring

I know the following xslt will work:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="test">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(title, 1, 4000)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

But not sure what to do if there is something like the following and you want the substring over the whole attribute value not just the title or the substitle.

```
    <xsl:attribute name="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
       <xsl:if test="../../sub_title != ''">
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="../sub_title"/>
    </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:attribute>
```

Is it even possible to apply a substring function over multiple lines that define an attribute?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Can you show the input XML?

Comment: Sorry I typed it in but obviously did not do the formatting write        <attribute name="test">

Comment: That still doesn't make sense.  You must have an XML document somewhere to which you're applying the XSLT.  Edit your powt and show the input XML (indent everything 4 spaces to have it formatted correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is that you want to build up a long string, consisting of the values of a number of other elements, and then truncate the result.

What you could do, is use the **concat** function to build the attribute value, and then do a substring on that.

```
<xsl:attribute name="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(title, ' ', ../sub_title), 1, 4000)" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

In this case, if **sub_title** was empty, you would end up with a space at the end of the **test** attribute, so you might want to add a **normalize-space** to this expression

```
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring(concat(title, ' ', ../sub_title), 1, 4000))" />
```

An alternate approach, if you did want to use a more complicated expression, is to do the string calculation in a variable first

```
<xsl:variable name="test">
   <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
   <xsl:if test="../../sub_title != ''">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../sub_title"/>
   </xsl:if>  
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:attribute name="test">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($test, 1, 4000)" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

As an aside, you can simplify your code by using "Attribute Value Templates" here, instead of using the more verbose **xsl:attribute** command. Simply do this..

```
<myElement test="{substring($test, 1, 4000)}">
```

Here, the curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally.